# Spring Security 5 OAuth 2.0 How does ResourceServer communicate with the AuthorizationServer?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I currently developing an internal project in my company that uses an authorization based on role access using spring security with OAuth2 and JWT.

I managed to develop the AuthorizationServer which simply return an access token with my custom claim.

I also already able to create the ResourceServer which able to decode the access token to validat the user role and access.

I have been following the RFC 6749 the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework.
which show a diagram like this:
[access and refresh token protocol flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBIJQ.png)

My question is how does the ResourceServer communicate with AuthorizationServer to validate the access token either the token is still valid or not?

[the questioned flow i had in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqFGa.png)

I research the answer to this question and found that the ResourceServer validate the token itself within the security filter chain, is this fully true?is there any answer about how the ResourceServer able to validate the token? Does the ResourceServer validate all the token when the ResourceServer endpoint get requested?
What if we want to manually trigger or validate the token, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for enlightenment, here is the explanation.

> **Question 1 (Q1):**
> How does the ResourceServer communicate with AuthorizationServer to validate the access token either the token is still valid or not?
>
> **Answer to Q1:**
> So in a sense we used asymmetric key (private-public key) in our authentication and authorization processes, we shared the public key to our Resource server and kept the private key in our Authorization server.
> We do this so that we can achieve the purpose of the separation of Authorization and Resource Server. The public key in Resource server is used when any request with the token coming to the Resource endpoint can be validated if the token was created from the Authorization Server which hold the correct pair of the private key.
>
> **Question 2 (Q2)**: "I research the answer to this question and found that the ResourceServer validate the token itself within the security
> filter chain, is this fully true?"
>
> **Answer to Q2:** It is true to some point if the JWT token used has invalid signature, the token cannot be converted into JSON so after that Resource Server will throw an error of invalid token.
>
> **Question 3 (Q3)**: is there any answer about how the ResourceServer able to validate the token?
>
> **Answer to Q3:** this answer is related with Q2 which is my only lead at current time.
>
> **Question 4 (Q4)**: Does the ResourceServer validate all the token when the ResourceServer endpoint get requested?
>
> **Answer to Q4:** Yes it does if you add @EnableResourceServer annotation and configure the endpoint correctly.
>
> **Question 5 (Q5)**:  What if we want to manually trigger or validate the token, is there anyway to do this?
>
> **Answer to Q5:** Still has not found any lead on this one.